# How to load response data and display on the react app using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I am trying to load the user data and display on my dashboard page, I have tried many methods but failed to do so. Anyone can help?

below is my dashboard page:

```
const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const { user } = props.auth;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
  }, []);
  
  return (<Fragment>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <i className='fas fa-user'></i>Welcome
    <p>{user && user.fullName}</p>
  </Fragment>);
};
```

below is my redux action:

```
export const getCurrentProfile = () => async dispatch => {
  const [user] = useState('')
  await authAxios.get('/user/profile').then(res => {
    const result = res.data.user.result;
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: you need to provide more info, about your state, your api call, what type of result do you get, do you get result or not? what is `result = res.data.user.result;` when you're dispatching `{
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    }`

Comment: have you verified that whether your `getCurrentProfile();` is returning some data or not ?

Comment: according to your code getCurrentProfile should be invoked like so `getCurrentProfile()(dispatch)`